# Embed JMX web viewer in application like jconsole

Tags: java, jmx, jconsole

I am looking for a embeded JMX web viewer in application like jconsole, so my background application can be monitored via http.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe [embedding hawtio](http://hawt.io/getstarted/#embedded) could be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `java attach apis` which allows you to attach a VM to your java process using `processid`. You can then create your own JMX agent.

More details here https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/the_attach_api

Comment: thanks, but I want a full functional web interface like jconsole